# Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be $n \times n$ matrices such that all of the following conditions hold:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be $n \times n$ matrices such that all of the following conditions hold:
a) $\det(A) \leq 0$

b) $A^{2}=I$ (identity matrix)

c)$ AB^{3}=I$

d) $AB=B^{3}A$

e) $ACA=BC$

Questions:

1) $\det(A)= ?? $

2) Find $(A+B)^{-1}$ in terms of the given matrices, or prove it does not exist.

3) Find $C^{-1}$ in terms of the given matrices, or prove it does not exist.

Comment: If $A^2=I$ then $1=\det(I)=\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2$ from where ...

Comment: Any thoughts about these questions?

Answer (score 3):

For question 1, since $\det(A)^2 = \det(A^2) = \det(I) = 1$, $\det(A) = -1$ by condition (a).

Multiply equation (b) by $A$ to get $A = A^2B^3 = B^3$. Substituting into equation (c) gives $AB = B^3A = A^2 = I$, multiplying by $A$ gives $A = A^2B = B$. Now we can solve question 2: $(A+B)^{-1} = (2A)^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}A^{-1}$ ($A$ is invertible since $\det(A) \neq 0$. Multiplying equation (b) by $A^{-1}$ gives $A = A^{-1}$ so the answer can be further simplified to $\frac{1}{2}A$.

Equation (e) can be written as $ACA = AC$, so we have $CA = C$. Suppose $C$ were invertible. Then multiplying by $C^{-1}$ gives $A = I$, which is a contradiction as $\det{A} = -1$. Hence $C$ is not invertible, answering question 3.

Comment: Let $n=1$, $A=B=-1$, $C=0$, the question does have a solution.

Comment: $B^3$ does not have to be equal to $I$.

Comment: Great job showing that $A=B$. =)

Comment: Im still having trouble seeing how A=B

Comment: @ArnaudD. My bad, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

($1$)

$$\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2=1$$

You are told that $\det(A) \leq 0$, can you conclude what is $\det(A)$?

($2$) One possible way is to prove that $A=B$. (Credit: @JeffreyDawson )

($3$) Take determinant of the last equation and cancel out similar terms. You should be able to conclude that $\det(C)=0$

Edit:
Proving $A=B$.

Comparing (b) and (c), we conclude that $A=B^3$ since they are both inverse of $A$ and inverse is unique. Substitute this into (d), we have $AB=A^2$ which leads to $A=B$ since $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Alternatively for $(3)$: cancel $A$ and $B$ on the left (since $A=B$) and deduce from $CA=C$ and $\det{A}\leq 0$ that $C$ cannot be invertible.

Comment: 1) For this one i found that def(A)= -1

Comment: 2) Im still having some problems trying to prove A=B. Im not sure where to start.

Comment: Edited my answer to prove $A=B$. You can also look at Jeffrey's solution.

Comment: How does proving A=B help find (A+B)^(-1) in terms of matrices?

Comment: $(A+B)^{-1}=(A+A)^{-1}$. Simplify it. In particular, you already know what is $A^{-1}$.

Comment: So just to make sure is the answer -2?

Comment: $$(A+B)=(2A)^{-1}=2^{-1}A^{-1}=\frac12 A$$

Note that from $A^2=I$, we know that $A^{-1}=A$

Comment: how do we know what A^(-1) is?

Comment: nevermind i see your note now